# How to set UiSearchBar Search icon on the right side in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I am working on Swift.

As regular SearchBar By default its appearing like Following Pic(1).
[image]

But as per our design requirement I need to change it as Following Pic(2).

[image]

I tried using the following code I got like Following Pic(3)

[image]

**When I tried the following code the right view is getting hide and I could not able to see the text field rightview

Search icon completely invisible**

```
let searchField = (searchBar.valueForKey("_searchField") as! UITextField)
searchField.layer.cornerRadius = 15;


    let searchIcon = searchField.leftView!
    if (searchIcon is UIImageView) {
        print("yes")
    }

    searchField.rightView = searchIcon
  searchField.leftViewMode = .Never
searchField.rightViewMode = .Always
```

Can anyone help me to get the requirement. I can understand if you provide even on objective C as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This , and call on  viewDidLayoutSubviews()

```
func SearchText(to searchBar: UISearchBar, placeHolderText: String) {
        searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.clear
        searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        searchBar.isTranslucent = true
        searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
        
        let searchTextField:UITextField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField ?? UITextField()
        searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        searchTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "search")!
        let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView.init(image: image)
        searchTextField.leftView = nil
         searchTextField.font = UIFont.textFieldText
        searchTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeHolderText,attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yourCOlur])
        searchTextField.rightView = imageView
        searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourCOlur
        searchTextField.rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
    }
```

Answer (score 21):

In ViewController, leftview of searchbar textfield is the actual search icon, so make it to nil and create a image view with custom icon and set as a right view of search textfield.

**Objective C**

```
@interface FirstViewController ()
{
    UISearchBar  *searchBar;
}
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(15, 100, 350,50);

    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UITextField *searchTextField = [((UITextField *)[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).subviews lastObject];
    searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
    searchTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    searchTextField.leftView = nil;

    searchTextField.placeholder = @"Search";

    searchTextField.rightView = imageView;
    searchTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}
```

**Swift**

```
    private var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 100, width: 350, height: 50)
        self.view.addSubview(searchBar)

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let searchTextField:UITextField = searchBar.subviews[0].subviews.last as! UITextField
        searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        searchTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "search")!
        let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView.init(image: image)
        searchTextField.leftView = nil
        searchTextField.placeholder = "Search"
        searchTextField.rightView = imageView
        searchTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    }
```

[image]

Comment: We have to set up searchTextField after viewDidLayoutSubviews(), but I don't know why. It seems searchTextField will cover your configuration set before viewDidLayoutSubviews().

Comment: Adding following code to viewDidLayoutSubviews() works for me thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to check Apple documentation [layoutIfNeeded()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622507-layoutifneeded)
 and [layoutSubviews()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) . You'll have better understanding after reading them. The magic happens when you write `searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()` instance method. Another solution is `searchBar.layoutSubviews()` but Apple documentation says:

> You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a
>   layout update, call the setNeedsLayout() method instead to do so prior
>   to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your
>   views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded() method.

According to @Jeyamahesan's answer. When you modify the code like below you do not need to separate the code in viewDidLoad() and ViewDidAppear().

**Example:**

```
import UIKit

class MainController: UIViewController {

    private var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 100, width: 350, height: 50)
        searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.addSubview(searchBar)

        let searchTextField:UITextField = searchBar.subviews[0].subviews.last as! UITextField
        searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        searchTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "Search")!
        let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView.init(image: image)
        searchTextField.leftView = nil
        searchTextField.placeholder = "Search"
        searchTextField.rightView = imageView
        searchTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    }
}
```

My approach to solve the issue:

**MainView.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MainView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupUI()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    private func setupUI() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        setupSubViews()
        setupAutoLayout()
    }

    // MARK: Initialize UI Elements
    private let searchBar: UISearchBar = {
        let searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.isTranslucent = false
        searchBar.barTintColor = ColorPalette.LuminousDay.white
        searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        return searchBar
    }()

    private let searchImageView: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImage(named: "Search")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    private lazy var searchBarTextField: UITextField = { [unowned self] in
        let textField = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchBarTextField") as! UITextField
        textField.font = FontBook.SourceSansPro.Weight.semiBold.setFont(size: 24)
        textField.textColor = ColorPalette.LuminousDay.charm
        textField.tintColor = ColorPalette.LuminousDay.charm
        textField.clearButtonMode = .never
        textField.leftViewMode = .never
        textField.leftView = nil
        textField.rightViewMode = .always
        textField.rightView = self.searchImageView
        return textField
    }()

    private func setupSubViews() {
        addSubview(searchBar)
        searchBar.addSubview(searchBarTextField)
        searchBarTextField.addSubview(searchImageView)
    }

    private func setupAutoLayout() {
        searchBar.anchor(top: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, bottom: nil,
                         leading: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, trailing: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                         centerX: nil, centerY: nil,
                         centerXconstant: nil, centerYconstant: nil,
                         size: CGSize.zero, padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))

        searchImageView.setSize(size: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))
    }
}
```

**MainController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MainController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = MainView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete search view customization with the storyboard in swift 5 and ios 13 or above

```
    @IBOutlet weak var searchview: UISearchBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    
        //make background vertical  line
        searchview.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                let searchTextField:UITextField = searchview.searchTextField
                searchTextField.textAlignment = .left
                searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 20
                searchTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
                searchTextField.rightView = nil

                //your custom icon here
                let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "Search")!
                let imageV:UIImageView = UIImageView.init(image: image)
                searchTextField.rightView = nil
                searchTextField.placeholder = "Search"
                searchTextField.leftView = imageV
                //dafault search icon
                let imageV = searchTextField.leftView as! UIImageView
                imageV.image = imageV.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
                imageV.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
                
            }
    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Switf 5**

Reference Jeyamahesan's answer。

I found viewDidLayoutSubviews is a better chance than viewDidAppear. If you call setupSearchTextField() in viewDidAppear, you will see a flash change on searchTextField.

Becasue viewDidLayoutSubviews will be called twice at first time, and be called many time later. so I add a isFirst variable.

R.string.localizable.product_name() -> It's a good resource framework, you can found more detail here.
https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift

```
private var isFirst = true
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    guard isFirst else {
    return
    }
    isFirst = false
    setupSearchTextField()
}

private func setupSearchTextField() {
    let searchTextField = searchBar.searchTextField
    searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
    searchTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hex: "707070").cgColor
    searchTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
    searchTextField.placeholder = R.string.localizable.product_name()
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: R.image.searchIcon())
    searchTextField.rightView = imageView
    searchTextField.rightViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always
    //delegate
    searchBar.delegate = self
}
```